# How to pass full data as it is without getting converted via GET?

Tags: django, get

I'm trying to manipulate my form's action via js with the following code:

```
form.action = "{% url 'search.html' phrase='developer' %}"
```

The problem is, it converts my data to weird signs instead of passing it as it is.

```
http://localhost:8000/%7B%%20url%20'search.html'%20phrase='developer'%20%%7D?
```

How can I avoid this convertion ?

Comment: That is because the `{% url ... %}` is *not* rendered. How do you render the template? Is the `form.action = ...` *part* of the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is, it converts my data to weird signs instead of passing it as it is.

**No**, it does not convert *anything*. It here simply uses `{% url 'search.html' phrase='developer' %}` as the *real* URL, and since a URL can not use `{`, `%`, etc. as characters, it uses [*percent encoding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Indeed, if you use for example a tool like [*url-encode-decode*](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/), then you will see that it will decode this to `{% url 'search.html' phrase='developer' %}`.

The reason this happens is because you apparently do *not* render that part of the template. This is for example the case if you use a JavaScript file that you thus serve as a static file.

You thus should make sure that the `{% url … %}` part is located in the *template*: a file where the template engine will *convert* this to a URL, not in a (static) file where Django never passes this to the template engine.